# Files partially downloading

Tags: download

I'm getting an odd problem when I try to download files from the internet. Typically the file appears to download correctly, but when I try to run it, I get an error message saying

> is not a valid win32
>   application.

On inspection the size of the file is not correct.

Here is an example that I tried 4 times. Only on the 4th attempt did it download correctly:

[image]

The file I happen to be trying to download is the [.net framework 1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=262d25e3-f589-4842-8157-034d1e7cf3a3&DisplayLang=en), but I've had it happen with others. I am using Firefox, but I get the same problem with IE.

Comment: Do you go through a proxy? Can you try "wget" or any download manager?

Comment: No. I don't go through proxy. Would really like to understand why it's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your picture shows different file sizes -- implies the download failed at times.
Consider using a download manager like [DownthemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/)

Comment: Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: network timeouts is one guess.

Comment: I have DownThemAll installed, and I now get this message for every file I download with it. Firefox's default Download Manager works fine though.